# Can't get for loop to cycle correctly

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I'm creating a weather app that takes a zip code and gives the current temp low and high for that day and also a future cast for the following six days. I'm also adding the functionality with the Date() function of having the correct days listed. But I'm having a problem when it cycles back thru to Sunday with it being at the 0 index in the array. I have a conditional testing for when the variable passes the number 6 and resets it to 0 so I don't run into any errors with undefined. Only problem is I'm still running into those problems. I'll leave the js code below it should be straight forward enough to where the html isn't needed. Also sorry in advance, I always screw up indention on here, lol. Any help is appreciated.

JS CODE BELOW

```
const weatherButton = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0];
const currentTemp = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__main--temp")[0];
const currentDayElement = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__lower--day")[0];
const futureDays = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__item--day");


//Adding functionality for setting days of week on button click
  weatherButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    let now = new Date();
    let currentDayIndex = now.getDay();
    currentDayElement.innerHTML = days[currentDayIndex];
    //Adding days for futurecast
    for( let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      if( currentDayIndex > 6 ) { currentDayIndex = 0 };
        futureDays[i].innerHTML = days[currentDayIndex + 1];
        currentDayIndex++;
    };
});
```

Comment: Because you are using “days[currentDayIndex + 1]”. That will make it go over. So you want to change the if condition to “currentDayIndex >= 6”. Another way to do is using modulus: “days[(currentDayIndex + 1 + i)%7]”. This way you can even ditch the if statement and the increment of currentDayIndex.

Comment: It's not the only problem in your code, you first defined *futureDays constant*, and later use *futureDays[i]* which also produces error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.weatherButton.addEventListener"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
days[currentDayIndex + 1]
```

when currentDayIndex is 0 and you add 1, you're starting at 1.

this is the for loop you'll want to use.

```
for(let i = 0, j = currentDayIndex + 1; i < 6; i++, j++){       
    if(j > 6){
      j = 0
    }
    futureDays[i].innerHTML = days[j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't know you could declare two variables in a for loop like that. I was trying to use an if else to test for when the index was at 7 and setting it back to 0 then a separate if conditional so that when the index was at 0 it would set it to sunday. But it was't working. Yours worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem! and now you know! Good luck in starting your JS career. If you ever have any other questions let me know. if you're a new dev consider watching my youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/omarsuriel

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you want:

```js
const weatherButton = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0];
const currentTemp = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__main--temp")[0];
const currentDayElement = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__lower--day")[0];
const futureDays = document.getElementsByClassName("weather__item--day");

weatherButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
 let now = new Date();
 let currentDayIndex = now.getDay();
 currentDayElement.innerHTML = days[currentDayIndex];
 //Adding days for futurecast
 for( let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  if( currentDayIndex >= 6 ) {
   currentDayIndex = 0;
   futureDays[0].innerHTML += '<div class="day">' + days[currentDayIndex] + '</div>';
  } else {
   futureDays[0].innerHTML += '<div class="day">' + days[currentDayIndex + 1] + '</div>';
   currentDayIndex++;
  }
 };
});
```

```html
weather__main--temp
<div class="weather__main--temp"></div>
weather__lower--day
<div class="weather__lower--day"></div>
weather__item--day
<div class="weather__item--day"></div>
button
<button id="button" style="width:100px; height:25px;">Click me!</button>
```